# Grouping by based on foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have the following rows in database
[image: this]

what is need is getting the following format in the response :

```
[
 ...,
 "centers":[
  {
   id:1,
   shifts:[
       {id:2},
       {id:4}
   ]
  }
 ]
]
```

But i what i am getting is like the following :

```
 [
 ...,
 "centers":[
  {
   id:1,
   shift_id : 2
  },
  {
   id:1,
   shift_id : 4
  }
 ]
]
```

This is my code trying to get what i want :

```
    $accountID = 1; 
    // final result is vechiles and it's related data
    $vehicles = Vehicle::where(['account_id'=>$accountID])->get()- 
    >map(function($item,$key) use ($accountID){
        $vehicleID = $item->id;
        // get centers whicr are belongs to for each vehicle
        $item['centers'] = Chv::where([['account_id',$accountID], 
    ['vehicle_id',$vehicleID]])->get();

        return $item;
    });
```

Models and db schema :

[image]

Comment: have u build the relationship between Chv and Shift model?

Comment: Yes, Chv is belongs to shift model

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `belongsToMany()` (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation to get your shifts:

**Model Center:**

```
public function shifts(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shift', 'chvs');
}
```

**And in your Code:**

```
$item['centers'] = Center::with('shifts')
      ->where([['center_id',$center_id],['account_id',$accountID],['vehicle_id',$vehicleID]])
      ->get();
```

Comment: In fact, center doesn't have a relationship with center directly, they related by chv model

Comment: So each chv belongs to shift and center and that means center and shift each of them hasMany chv records

Comment: please share your DB schema for those 3 models in your question and let me know when done

Comment: I couldn't understand how can i add shifts relationship in Center model  while there is no relationship between them?
also can you clarify role_user according to my models relationships?

Comment: @FadiRamzi not `role_user`, chvs as pivot table. you can create many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @TsaiKoga good catch, and bad copypaste from my side - updated

Comment: I got error : 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException: Call to undefined relationship [shifts] on model [App\Models\Chv]

as i read in the doc. i don't need to add any method like shifts in Chv model

Comment: Please check the udpated answer, it's `Center::` and not `Chc::`

Comment: could you review my latest code updates
it is all my function body code to obtains the result